# java.lang.NullPointerException  Проблема с загрузкой класса.

Tags: java

Выбрасывается java.lang.NullPointerException

```
Class.forName("Essence.Users");
Users.AllUsers.printer();  // Выбрасывается в этой строке.
```

Вот класс Users.

```
public class Users 
        {
     public static Users AllUsers;
         private ArrayList <UserThread> Users;

         public void printer()
                     {
                      System.out.print("xxxxxx");
                     }

         private Users()
                {
                 System.out.print("Обьект создался.");
                 Users = new ArrayList <UserThread>();
                }

         static
         {
          Users AllUsers = new Users();
         }
        }
```

Comment: А "Обьект создался." выводится?

Comment: @Котик, верните ответ, он был правильный :)

Comment: @VladD Да я еще думал проверить, какие там условия вызова `static` в стандарте, но, в общем, ладно :)

Comment: Насколько я помню, блок static вызвается не позже, чем первое обращение к любому полю/методу класса, будь оно статическим или нет. Не уверен насчёт рефлексии.

Comment: @Котик: нашёл место в [спецификации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/): раздел 12.4.1. Рефлексия тоже вошла в список:

> Invocation of certain reflective methods in class `Class` and in package `java.lang.reflect` also causes class or interface initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Вы в вашем статическом конструкторе создали **локальную** переменную `AllUsers` типа `Users`, а не проинициализировали соответствующее поле класса `Users`.

> Видимо, имелось ввиду следующее: `static { AllUsers = new Users() }`

- `Class.forName` здесь совершенно лишний - статический конструктор вызывается при создании инстанса класса или попытке обращения к статическим полям класса.

Comment: Вы правы!) Спасибо.
Невнимательность опасна.